# why using arrow function is causing error in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing an application in React but these errors are causing troubles.
This is my code -

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const LINKS = [
  { to: '/', text: 'Home' },
  { to: '/starred', text: 'Starred' },
];

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {LINKS.map(item => (
          <li key={item.to}>
            <Link to={item.to}>{item.text}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

const Navbar is producing these 2 errors
Line 3:17:  Function component is not a function declaration
Line 3:23:  Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`

When i am try to fix the problem VScode changes the code to -

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {LINKS.map(item => (
          <li key={item.to}>
            <Link to={item.to}>{item.text}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but i want to use const arrow function in my code please provide me the solution
[image: There are errors in problem col as well as in terminal also when i am disabling the react definition]

[image]

[image: But when i add this two more lines the errors in problem column is removed but it terminal this error exists]

Comment: That code is perfectly fine. What tool is it giving you the error, some linter?

Comment: @Takkie253 - There's no need for them, the absense shouldn't be causing an issue with any half-decent linter. (Other than that the linter may explicitly say you need `()` around the parameter as with ESLint's `arrow-parens`.)

Comment: @Takkie253 `item => {...}` is most certainly not the problem, as it is also contained in the working code ... Furthermore, it doesn't change anything in that context if you have `(item) => { ... }` or `item => { ... }`

Comment: the `eslint-plugin-react` has a rule, that a named function component must not be an arrow function ... https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/function-component-definition.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an `eslint` error since it isn't any errors in your code but instead that you don't follow your eslint-rules. This specific error message seems to refer to `react/function-component-definition` rule.

> This option enforces a specific function type for function components.

[ESLint Rule](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/function-component-definition.md)

Go to your eslint configuration and either remove or override this rule and turn it off by setting it to `0` or `off`

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [...],
  rules: {
    ...,
    "react/function-component-definition": 0,
  },
};
```

Comment: I added this rule to my ,eslintrc but does't changes anything it again gives the same error, but i have got a solution.                                                                                                  "rules": {
    "react/function-component-definition": [2],
    "namedComponents": "arrow-function",
    "unnamedComponents": "arrow-function"
  },                                                                                                                                          //This Worked for me.

Comment: Glad it got resolved.

Comment: It is again causing problem now, i don't know what to do i have tried this all but nothing working for me,